# How to create quintiles in from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with column factorvalue. I want to create quintiles for the colmun factorvalue and box plot the quintiles. I also want to group by date

Comment: show what have you tried already, input, and expected output

Comment: Could you share some code? (So that we can see where you're stuck). Additionally have you checked this:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"factorvalue":[round(random.uniform(0,5),3) for i in range(200)]})

(df
    .assign(quantile=pd.qcut(df["factorvalue"].values, q=3), dtype="object")
    .pivot(columns="quantile", values="factorvalue")
    .boxplot()
)
```

[image]